# modifying devise default error messages in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using **devise gem** in my rails app and this is my screenshot  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBlvl.png. How do I remove those default red colored errors? Thanks in advance,

Comment: comment out  `devise_error_messages!` from your form ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `rails generate devise:views` so you can override the devise views on your views/devise folder. In that case, I believe it's the `sessions/new` view. I think it's the better way to do that!